# freenx server, with nomachine nxclient - I can not disconnect, only log out

Tags: 12.04, freenx

I used this guide http://www.drivard.com/2012/06/installation-freenx-server-ubuntu-12-04-lts-precise/ to install freenx and it is working fine apart from 1 thing.

I can't seem to be able to disconnect from sessions.
If I try to close (from the 'X' button top right) a NXsession from the client pc nothing will happen. In other setups where I use NX to forward desktops sessions,  I would get a gtk , or ncurses windows asking me if I want to terminate (=log out), or disconnect from the session.

In this case nothing happens when I press 'X', and I can only choose to log out from the session (as I would locally).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I stumbled upon a solution on your issue.

for some reason the pull down menu on the destop that opens up for me does not include a Logoff or anything of that sort but...

When I hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> I get the Disconnect or logoff dialogue window.

Comment: @rambammram in ncurses or gtk widget ? I have long switched to nomachine's NX client, node & server to get that functionality.... Thank you though